# Getting "cannot import name 'layers' from 'keras'" while importing keras

Tags: keras, python-import

I was importing keras in my jupyter notebook, but I'm getting **cannot import name 'layers' from 'keras'**

Traceback:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9104\626967271.py in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 import keras
      3 from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet101
      4 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
      5 from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

c:\users\vikram g t\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     19 """
     20 from keras import distribute
---> 21 from keras import models
     22 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     23 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential

c:\users\vikram g t\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18 from keras.engine.functional import Functional
     19 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential
     20 from keras.engine.training import Model

c:\users\vikram g t\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py in <module>
     32 from keras.engine import input_spec
     33 from keras.engine import node as node_module
---> 34 from keras.engine import training as training_lib
     35 from keras.engine import training_utils
     36 from keras.saving.legacy import serialization

c:\users\vikram g t\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in <module>
     31 from keras.engine import base_layer
     32 from keras.engine import base_layer_utils
---> 33 from keras.engine import compile_utils
     34 from keras.engine import data_adapter
     35 from keras.engine import input_layer as input_layer_module

c:\users\vikram g t\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py in <module>
     22 
     23 from keras import losses as losses_mod
---> 24 from keras import metrics as metrics_mod
     25 from keras.saving.experimental import saving_lib
     26 from keras.utils import generic_utils

c:\users\vikram g t\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\__init__.py in <module>
     31 # Metric functions
     32 # Individual metric classes
---> 33 from keras.metrics.metrics import AUC
     34 from keras.metrics.metrics import Accuracy
     35 from keras.metrics.metrics import BinaryAccuracy

c:\users\vikram g t\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\metrics.py in <module>
     26 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
     27 
---> 28 from keras import activations
     29 from keras import backend
     30 from keras.dtensor import utils as dtensor_utils


c:\users\vikram g t\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py in <module>
     19 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
     20 
---> 21 import keras.layers.activation as activation_layers
     22 from keras import backend
     23 from keras.saving.legacy import serialization

ImportError: cannot import name 'layers' from 'keras'
```

I didn't find any solutions regarding this issue in stack overflow, need help about what to do. I'll be trying with Google colabs, hoping it will work.
I was expecting keras to be imported successfully